# No Numeric Type To Aggregate

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I have a dataframe in which there is the following columns:

```
Date - Seller - Amount
```

Code sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
testframe = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/02/2019', '01/02/2019', '01/02/2019', 
'02/02/2019','02/02/2019','03/02/2019'], 
'Seller': ['John', 'Ada', 'John', 'Ada', 'Ada', 'Ada'], 'Amount': 
[150,200,158,200,60,90]})
```

I aggregated the data so:

```
agg=pd.DataFrame(base.groupby(['date','Seller'])['Amount'].sum())
agg.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then I tried, using FacetGrid, to display the Amount along the days per Seller(each row from FacetGrid would be a row). Like so:

```
g=sns.FacetGrid(data=agg,row='Seller')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'Amount', 'date')
```

But I get the following error:

> No numeric types to aggregate

There was another post here on Stackoverflow, but didn't quite give a me clue about what to do in order to solve.

I checked the variables from packages and it returned numpy.int64. I tried to convert'em to float and int using `.astype()` but didn't work too.

Environment: Jupyter Notebook

Can someone shed a light on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] when asking about undesired behaviour in code.

Comment: Sorry ! Didn't know it was a good practice. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you mean something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


base = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/02/2019', '01/02/2019', '01/02/2019', 
                                   '02/02/2019','02/02/2019','03/02/2019'], 
    'Seller': ['John', 'Ada', 'John', 'Ada', 'Ada', 'Ada'], 'Amount': 
            [150,200,158,200,60,90]})


base["date"] = pd.to_datetime(base["date"])

agg=pd.DataFrame(base.groupby(['date','Seller'])['Amount'].sum())
agg.reset_index(inplace=True)


g=sns.FacetGrid(data=agg, row='Seller')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'date', 'Amount')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that John's plot is empty because he only sold something on a single day, and one cannot draw a line from a point to itself.

Comment: I forgot to use the pd.to_datetime!
Thanks a lot for the help